# Z = $Y$ $X_1$ + $(1-Y)$ $X_2$. where Y is a Bernoulli random variable. Calculate characteristic function of Z

Tags: probability, probability-theory, characteristic-functions

Let Z = $Y$ $X_1$ + $(1-Y)$ $X_2$, where Y is a Bernoulli random variable. Y is independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$.
Find the characteristic function of Z.

It's posible calculate the characteristic function of Z whithout know $X_1$ and $X_2$? How?

Comment: Please write the definition of "characteristic function" for $Z$, then substitute the definition of $Z$.  In other words, you should proceed as far as you can, and the first few steps should be automatic (i.e., just apply the definition for this particular case). You may see a way to keep going if you do those first few steps.